# Google Location search within a specific country without showing map in asp.net textbox

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to use google location search api for searching my country(Bangladesh) location in my c# asp.net application without showing map.please give a details idea about google location search api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey bro you can use this as follows:in aspx page due to header section

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAaczGkYJhz_uP1Xo03sWxYnBB7R1NXzZE&sensor=false&libraries=places&language=eng&types=establishment"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

function SearchAddressByGoogle() {

        var options = {
            // types: ['(cities)'],
            componentRestrictions: { country: "bd" }//Here bd for bangladesh location only
        };

        var input = document.getElementById('Your_Search_TextBox_Name');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
    }
```

in your .cs file

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    {
      Your_Search_TextBox_Name.Attributes.Add("onkeyUp", "SearchAddressByGoogle();");
    }
```

or this is another process

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAaczGkYJhz_uP1Xo03sWxYnBB7R1NXzZE&sensor=false&libraries=places&language=eng&types=establishment"

<script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {

        var options = {
            // types: ['(cities)'],
            componentRestrictions: { country: "bd" }
        };

        var input = document.getElementById('Your_Search_TextBox_Name');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

For more details about google map api follow the link bellow:[Click Here](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/#PlaceSearchRequests).

For google api key see the link [Click for key details](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/mapkey)